# Where could I get systems for the Warframe Oberon?

Tags: warframe

I try to do every mission on Earth to find all Oberon's part, but I can't find the system part. Do you know where I can find it, even with a small drop rate?

I did every mission approximately 10 times, and still no systems...

**NOTE**: There's only 1 mission I can't do. It's the final one, which needs me to be mastery rank 4 or 5 (I'm lvl 3 ATM).

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fastest way to farm eximus units for Oberon is by playing a sortie mission with the "eximus stronghold" condition.  I rarely come out without a full set or near full set of Oberon.

Comment: Ok thx, will try that ^^ Do I need a higher mastery level to play sortie mission?

Comment: You need to be at least MR 4 to gain access to the daily sortie missions (according to the wiki).  If you're already MR 3, then just start getting to work on ranking up more weapons, and you'll be MR 4 in no time.

Comment: Ok,just 5k remaining and it's ok. Just some weapons to up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can drop from any Eximus unit, so there is no specific system that you would need to farm - instead you should focus on high level missions. Interception missions are specified in the quote below as, if done right, you can prolong them for a very long time, assuming a good group, to ensure high amounts of Eximus spawns.

From the [WARFRAME-wikia page on Oberon](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Oberon):

> **All Eximus units have a 1% chance to drop a blueprint**, and if they do, it's a 38.72% chance each for Oberon's Helmet and Chassis, and **22.56% for his Systems**. Hence the total probabilities are 0.3872% and 0.2256% respectively, resulting in 605 expected required Eximus kills to obtain the full set. Therefore, in order to explicitly search Oberon components, it is recommended to do missions with high Eximus density, like Sorties or high level Interception missions.

You can [not trade non-Prime Blueprints](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Trade_System) except for Nezha, so trading with higher level players is not an option (thanks to MacedonZero for the heads-up).

Comment: I thought the only non-prime warframe that could be traded was Nezha?

Comment: @MacedonZero You do have a point, Ill edit it.